# Two different form registration

Tags: magento2, customer, forms

I created under my theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form:register.phtml and register2.phtml and i put this in customer_account_create under mytheme/Magento_Customer/layout, and i created  a module to have  a route that lead to the second form and i overrided again under layout of my new module the customer_account_create.xml to just show the address in the form and i put in the layout of my new module newcust_index_index :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register_2" template="Magento_Customer::form/register2.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I got this as result in customer/account/create (the form is duplicated ):[image]

and in the new form i got this :[image]

the customer_account_create layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register_2" template="Magento_Customer::form/register2.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the line below within the body directive of your layout file: that should remove the form you don't need:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" remove="true" />
```

Comment: can you please explain more and thanks for your replay

Comment: apologies, the mentioned line was not appearing. It does now appear, the line now appearing fine should be self-explanatory. If not, do let me know

Comment: excuse me but i want to have the address fields in the two form  name=customer_form_register and name=customer_form_register why removing that from the first form

Comment: ok, I must have misunderstood.